# SonarQube Runner skips JavaScript files in Asp.Net MVC solution

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sonarqube

It was a long WTF moment and I could not find any information on the issue, so I decided I put it here.

**Setup**: Windows 7 x86_64, sonarqube-4.3, sonar-runner-2.4, jre 1.7.0_55-b14

I followed [quick start guide](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Setup+and+Upgrade) to configure Sonar.

I copied sonar-project.properties from a [sample](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/projects/languages/csharp/sonar-project.properties) to my solution, put it in the directory with .sln, and made necessary adjustments:

> sonar.projectKey=org.whatever.project
>   sonar.projectName=Project
>   sonar.projectVersion=2.0
>   sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
>   sonar.sources=.
>   sonar.visualstudio.enable=true

**Problem**: Analysis ran without any exceptions but only C# files were analyzed.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, following line in config was causing the issue:

> sonar.sources=.

After moving sonar-project.properties one level up and changing it accordingly, the problem was resolved.

> sonar.sources=src

Answer (score 0):

I think it actually relates to the usage of the Visual Studio Bootstrapper. Can you try the same without it?

Here is what happens: The Visual Studio bootstrapper reads all the `<Compile>` tags from the *.csproj files to determine which files must be imported. Javascript files are not referenced by `<Compile>` (as they do not need to be compiled), and will therefore not be imported in SonarQube.

See this related Jira ticket: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARVS-27